# Interpolating monthly dates between two months in R

Tags: r, date

I have two dates in R, and I want to create a vector of the dates in between them spaced at one-month intervals. However, R seems to be using 31-day intervals instead (sometimes?). For example:

```
x <- as.Date("31-01-1900", "%d-%m-%Y")
y <- as.Date("31-01-1901", "%d-%m-%Y")
seq(x, y, by="month")

 [1] "1900-01-31" "1900-03-03" "1900-03-31" "1900-05-01" "1900-05-31"
 [6] "1900-07-01" "1900-07-31" "1900-08-31" "1900-10-01" "1900-10-31"
[11] "1900-12-01" "1900-12-31" "1901-01-31"
```

What I wanted was a vector of dates, each of which is the final day in each month, like this:

```
 [1] "1900-01-31" "1900-02-29" "1900-03-31" "1900-04-30" "1900-05-31"
 [6] "1900-06-30" "1900-07-31" "1900-08-31" "1900-09-30" "1900-10-31"
[11] "1900-11-30" "1900-12-31" "1901-01-31"
```

Does R know the lengths of the months, or do I have to do it by hand?

Comment: You may take a look at the `lubridate` package, however this is an excerpt from ?seq.POSIXt: "Using "month" first advances the month without changing the day: if this results in an invalid day of the month, it is counted forward into the next month." So it looks like this is fixed in these functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate a sequence of the first of each month, then subtract 1

```
seq(as.Date("1900-02-01"), length = 12, by="1 month") - 1
# [1] "1900-01-31" "1900-02-28" "1900-03-31" "1900-04-30" "1900-05-31" "1900-06-30"
# [7] "1900-07-31" "1900-08-31" "1900-09-30" "1900-10-31" "1900-11-30" "1900-12-31"

## the same can be achieved with `seq.Date()`
# seq.Date(as.Date("1900-02-01"), by = "1 month", length.out = 12) - 1
```

Comment: Both answers are very good, but I prefer this one because it does not require a package.

Comment: me too; I generaly try to go for a base R solution first.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
x <- as.Date("31-01-1900", "%d-%m-%Y")
y <- as.Date("31-01-1901", "%d-%m-%Y")
c(x, x %m+% months(1:11), y)

[1] "1900-01-31" "1900-02-28" "1900-03-31" "1900-04-30"
[5] "1900-05-31" "1900-06-30" "1900-07-31" "1900-08-31"
[9] "1900-09-30" "1900-10-31" "1900-11-30" "1900-12-31"
[13] "1901-01-31"
```

Or, equivalently, and probably a little easier to read:

```
lubridate::add_with_rollback(x, months(0:12))

 [1] "1900-01-31" "1900-02-28" "1900-03-31" "1900-04-30"
 [5] "1900-05-31" "1900-06-30" "1900-07-31" "1900-08-31"
 [9] "1900-09-30" "1900-10-31" "1900-11-30" "1900-12-31"
[13] "1901-01-31"
```